# Select multiple objects and save to ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="contact.groups" 
        ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in groups" 
        ng-multiple="true" multiple>

        <option value="">Choose groups</option>
</select>
```

`contact.groups` contains a list of groups assigned to the contact:

```
[
   {
     id: 145,
     name: 'FooBar
   }
]
```

`groups` is a list of all available groups. First problem is that item.id in ng-options displays not the correct ID of the group but   seems to count from 0 (first group in list), 1 (second group in list), etc

Second problem is that contact.groups is not taken into account, there is no pre-selected groups in the select field.

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Jy643/1/

Any ideas how to handle this problem?

Comment: it works as expected, make sure you push only the `id` in the tracking collection and not the whole object http://jsfiddle.net/Jy643/2/

Comment: Yeah dude, it works. [http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/Jy643/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/Jy643/3/)

Comment: @KrisIvanov I updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Jy643/4/ it does not work if the model comes with data

Comment: I don't think ng-multiple="true" does anything?

Comment: @wbeange - I think you're right - ng-multiple="false" was supposed to create a single-select listbox, but its a bit flaky, and there's no doc for ngMultiple that I can find.

Comment: @artworkadシ you are not initializing it right. It should be like: 
    $scope.contact = {name: 'Bob', groups: [143]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngOptions compares objects by strict equality, meaning your model group needs to be a reference to one of the group in `$scope.groups`:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.test = "Das ist ein Test";
    $scope.groups = [{id: 142, name: 'Foo'},{id: 143, name: 'Bar'}, {id: 144, name: 'Bas'}];

    $scope.contact = {name: 'Bob', groups: [{id: 143}]};
    $scope.contact = {name: 'Bob', groups: $scope.groups[1]};
}
```

<kbd>[**PLUNKER**](http://jsfiddle.net/GV9Ek/)</kbd>

Comment: +1 thank you for this info. So I have to re initialize contact.groups?? like this  http://jsfiddle.net/GV9Ek/1/  ?? See the nested loop

Answer (score 1):

Try using 'track by tracking_expression' into ngOptions (also run on ngRepeat) that allow match objects by expresion instead of reference.
[Angular Select Documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)