# How to use selects with same options on angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a question about how to use selects with same options on angular.

I have an example about a user that have to **select one or many options of his favorites sports and set a puntuation for each option selected**:

this is my code:

```
<div class="form-group m-b-md">
  <selectize config='optionsConfig' options='sports' ng-model=""></selectize>
</div>
<input type="number" min="1" ng-model="" required>
```

my options are:

```
optionSelect:['soccer', 'basket', 'tennis', 'baseball']
```

and i have tu push his options to an array like this way

```
sportsPoints[
  {
    sport: 'futbol',
    points: 10
  },
  {
    sport: 'tennis',
    points: 4
  },
]
```

but what ng-model do i have to set, because if a set one like sportsOptions, and select an option both select are gonna have the same option selected!

what can i do in this case?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried ng-multiple="true"?
Seems like similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305489/select-multiple-objects-and-save-to-ng-model

Comment: it is something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/oxtojjEPwkKng9iKkc14?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can work around with radio buttons:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.selectedSports = [];
  $scope.optionSelect = ['soccer', 'basket', 'tennis', 'baseball'];
  $scope.addSport = function() {
    $scope.selectedSports.push({sport: $scope.sport, points: $scope.points});
    $scope.sport = null;
    $scope.points = null;
  };
})
```

and on html:

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
  <div ng-repeat="option in optionSelect">
    <input type="radio" name="sport" ng-model="$parent.sport" ng-value="option" />{{option}}
  </div>
  Quantity: <input type="number" name="option" ng-model="points"/>
  <input type="button" ng-click="addSport()" value="Add" ng-disabled="sport == null || points == null" /><br/>
  {{selectedSports}}
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/diegopolido/qgu7otrr/2/

Comment: in my case would be something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/oxtojjEPwkKng9iKkc14?p=preview